# Perl error Bad Gateway only when using peronal module Busybox

Tags: perl, module, openwrt, busybox

I am new to perl and have written a script with a per module, it works from command line and displays the desired html, but when I run it via http I get a Bad Gateway error.  It I place the entire script in one file without calling the self made module it will run. I am running it on Busybox. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;
use myperlfunc;

#get Wifi info
wifi_info ();

# generate the page
http_header();
html_header("Scan",1);
navibar("Scan");
Create_scan_buttons ( );
scan_button_actions ( );
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";


######
myperlfunc;


sub http_header                         
{                                       
# print "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"; 
print "Cache-Control: no-store\r\n";  
#  print "\r\n";                       
}                                      

##start HTML Page##                    
sub html_header                        
{                                     
my($title, $close) = @_;           
print "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n";
print "<html>\n";                                                       
print "<head>\n";                                                           
print "<title>$title</title>\n";                                            
print "<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>\n";                          
print "<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>\n";             
print "<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>\n";                    
print qq {<link href="../Site.css" rel="stylesheet">}; #used instead of escaping to print stylesheet
print "</head>\n";                                                                                  
print "<body>";                                                                                     
print "<H1><center>Welcome to bla bla  <br>bla bla bla...</H1>" if $close;                          

}                                                                                                  

1;
```

Comment: Note: Different header lines are separated by a single return.  The header itself is separated from the rest of the content by a double return.  So your header function should be: `print "Content-type: text/plain\n"; print "Cache-Control: no-store\n\n";`

Comment: Also, for multiple lines of html content, it is often better to use either `qq{}` like you did for your one line, or even better just use a HERE_DOC so you can group all the lines into a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved version, but there's still work to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use myperlfunc;

sub http_header {
   print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
   print "Cache-Control: no-store\r\n";
}

##start HTML Page##
sub html_header {
my ( $title, $close ) = @_;
print <<EOT;
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>$title</title>
 <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
 <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
 <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
 <link href="../Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
 #used instead of escaping to print stylesheet
</head>
<body>
EOT

print "<H1><center>Welcome to bla bla  <br>bla bla bla...</H1>" if $close;

}
#get Wifi info
wifi_info();
# generate the page

http_header();
html_header( "Scan", 1 );
navibar("Scan");
create_scan_buttons();
scan_button_actions();
print "</body>\n";
print "</html>\n";

# what is this mean to do?
myperlfunc;

exit 0;
```

A number of things here:

- What's in myperlfunc? scan_button_actions etc.?
- myperlfunc by itself on a line doesn't do anything
- The code doesn't exit, I added that, maybe that's the 502 error
- In general it's useful to know about the rest of it. myperlfunc etc.
- For a 502 it's useful to know how the web server is set up too...
- Perltidy is your friend!
- The Perl debugger is your friend!
- perl -c name-of-script to test syntax is your friend!

Hope that helps, but there's a few things that could be wrong here.